# Finding the maximum magnitude of an electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

I'm working on a lab report on electric fields and I need to calculate the magnitude of the maximum electric field given by the formula
                      $E=  ∆φ/∆s,  $

where ∆φ is the change in potential in the distance ∆s. But I'm not getting how to find ∆φ and how to find the maximum electric field in my graph.

(distances in mm)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equipotential lines are like contour lines on a map which connect land which is at the same height above sea level.  Finding the electric field is like finding the slope on the map.  The slope (the steepest line of ascent or descent) is always perpendicular to the contour lines, and it is steepest where the contour lines are closest together (provided that the same increment between contours is used in the comparison - eg every 10m of height).

In your graph the equipotential lines are all in increments of 1V, so the greatest electric field (steepest slope) will be in regions where the equipotential lines are closest together.  That is clearly on the RHS of the graph, with co-ordinates (11-19, 24) approx.  The electric field is the difference in potential between two contours (here 1V), divided by the perpendicular distance between the contours (about 0.5mm).  So the highest value of E is about 1V/0.5mm=2V/mm.

Comment: thanks now i understand it , Is it possible to find the error of the measurement distance and the voltage so i can find the error of value E

Comment: or the error of the voltage should be given by the measuring tool

Comment: It is difficult to estimate the error from the graph because it is not known whether the variations in the positions of data points accurately depict the real electric field or they are due to measurement errors.  Unless you know which it is, I would assume the distance between equipotentials is uncertain by about 0.5mm, so the error is about +/- 1V/mm.